# Javascript/Ajax upside down .append?

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and sending a message to the client with data it should append to a div:

```
socket.on('new data', function(data){
    $('#container').append('<div id="newDATA">data</div>');
});
```

It works fine, but is there a way I can make it append the data upside down? I mean, instead of appending the data bellow the older data it will append above.
like:

data3 (latest)

data2

data1

Comment: also make sure the id of div that you are appending is dynamic/unique

Comment: It looks to me like you are using jQuery and that the problem has nothing to do with Ajax. As @Cyval stated `.prepend()` gives you the desired output via jQuery.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that function. Thank You very much. Make it an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @E.Sundin You're right, I mistook Jquery/Ajax

Comment: Right in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/): *"The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first child, use .prepend())."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.append()` , as the name says, appends something to the bottom an element. 
In this case, you should use `.prepend`. Remember that `pre` means `before`.

```
socket.on('new data', function(data){
     $('#container').prepend('<div id="newDATA">data</div>');
});
```

Comment: 6 minutes before I can accept it. Thank You very much!

Comment: No problem @MarcielFonseca.

Comment: Can i .prepend to .append?
Because it reverses my data, is that possible?

Comment: Can you provide an example please? @Darktwen

Comment: I do not need that anymore i changed my code, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has both `.append()` and `.prepend()` functions. One adds to the bottom of the parent element, the other to the top. Sounds like you need the latter.